# C. the prints don't come out right, so far haven't been able to figure out why

Tags: c, string, printf

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void splitString(char s[]) {

    char firstHalf[100] = { 0 };
    char secndHalf[100] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s) / 2; i++){
        firstHalf[i] = s[i];
    }

    for (int i = strlen(s) /2; i < strlen(s); i++){
        secndHalf[i - strlen(s) / 2] = s[i];
    }

    printf("The string split in two is '%s, - %s' \n", firstHalf, secndHalf);
}

void upperCase(char s[]){

    //String in upper case
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    s[i] = toupper(s[i]);

        printf("The string in uppercase is '%s'", s);
}

void lowerCase(char s[]){

    //String in lower case
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);

        printf("The string in lowercase is '%s'", s);
}

int main() {

    char s[200];
    char splitS[200];

    printf("Type a string: ", sizeof( s));

    if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != 0){
        printf("The string is '%s'", s);
    }

    strcpy(splitS, s);

    upperCase(s);
    lowerCase(s);
    splitString(splitS);

    return 0;
}
```

**The correct way it's supposed to print is like this:**

> The string is 'Hello world'
>
> The string in uppercase is 'HELLO WORLD'
>
> The string in lowercase is 'hello world'
>
> The string split in two is 'Hello, - world'

**But instead it prints like this:**

> The string is 'Hello world
>
> 'The string in uppercase is 'HELLO WORLD
>
> 'The string in lowercase is 'hello world
>
> 'The string split in two is 'Hello , - world
>
> '

Comment: `printf("Type a string: ", sizeof( s));`.. WTH is this?

Comment: Consider flushing the `stdout`.....

Comment: either `fflush()`,or, `stdout` being line buffered, use `\n` at end of each format string.

Comment: Make sure the string you have input (that is, after `fgets`) does not contain a terminating newline character. That newline gets printed out by `printf`-s and mis-formats your results. :)

Comment: Oh, and add a newline (`\n`) at the end of each output formatting string; that will help you see what's going on.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve].  The `upperCase()`, `lowerCase()`, and `splitString()` are all irrelevant - your problem is adequately demonstrated with just the `gets()`+`printf()`, and more likely to attract good, targeted answers were you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [documentation for `fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) (my emphasis):

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.** A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Since you are typing in these lines with line break characters at the end, you need to remove them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put null terminator

```
void splitString(char s[]) {

char firstHalf[100] = { 0 };
char secndHalf[100] = { 0 };

// u need to add null terminator '\0' at the end of string
// so u can add it in for loop or set i outside of loop

for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s) / 2; i++){
    firstHalf[i] = s[i];
    **firstHalf[i+1] = '\0';**
}

for (size_t i = strlen(s) /2; i < strlen(s); i++){
    secndHalf[i - strlen(s) / 2] = s[i];
    **secndHalf[i+1] = '\0';**
}

printf("The string split in two is '%s, - %s' \n", firstHalf, secndHalf);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `fgets` function will read a newline and append it to the input string of there's room for it.

You need to check if the last character in the string is `\n` and if so set it to zero to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `fgets` retains a `newline` at the end of the input string, and also because you do not printf a `newline` yourself.

So the result, is that `newline` is being printed in the wrong place, splitting your message, and the `'` appears on the next line.

An easy way to remove the `newline` from the entry is with

```
s [ strcspn(s, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

but don't forget to add the `\n` to the end of the `printf` formatting strings.

Answer (score 0):

I thing use `scanf` with format specifier `%[^\n]s` so you can skip the new line instated of `fgets` and add `\n` in every `printf`.

Complete working code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void splitString(char s[]) {

    char firstHalf[100] = { 0 };
    char secndHalf[100] = { 0 };
int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(s) / 2; i++){
        firstHalf[i] = s[i];
    }

    for ( i = strlen(s) /2; i < strlen(s); i++){
        secndHalf[i - strlen(s) / 2] = s[i];
    }

    printf("\n The string split in two is '%s, - %s' \n", firstHalf, secndHalf);
}

void upperCase(char s[]){

    //String in upper case
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    s[i] = toupper(s[i]);

        printf("\n The string in uppercase is '%s'", s);
}

void lowerCase(char s[]){

    //String in lower case
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);

        printf("\n The string in lowercase is '%s'", s);
}

int main() {

    char s[200];
    char splitS[200];

    printf("Type a string: %ld", sizeof( s));

    if (scanf("%200[^\n]s", s)!= 0){  //fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) 
        printf("\n The string is '%s'", s);
    }

    strcpy(splitS, s);

    upperCase(s);
    lowerCase(s);
    splitString(splitS);

    return 0;
}
```

**OR**

if you want use `fgets` only then find new line char in string and make it `NULL` and add new line char `'\n'`  in every `printf` .

Code need to change is:

```
 if ( fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != 0){   
     int  i;
     for(i = 0 ; i < sizeof( s) ; i++ ){
          if(s[i] == '\n'){
               s[i] = '\0';     
               break;
          }
      }
    printf("\n The string is '%s'", s); 
 }
```

Comment: It's just that the teacher wanted us to use fgets, as having a limit to a string written by a user could be dangerous. Not sure if I completely understood how it could be dangerous, but think it has something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf

Comment: @Zuflus correct but to avoid buffer overflow i have given limit in the `scanf` that is `%200....` so it will be ok to use scanf.